# DSS WSDL1.1 WCF gives Cannot import wsdl:binding, Cannot import wsdl:port, Cannot import wsdl:

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I have a WSO2 Data Service which I am taking the WSDL 1.1 and trying to add a Service Reference ins VS2010 using WCF and it generates 3 WSDL errors which I can't figure out.

```
    Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='MzpIDMgmtHttpBinding'] C:\dev\AssociateEntityService\AssociateEntityService\Service References\MzIdManagementServiceReference\Reference.svcmap 1   1   AssociateEntityService

Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='MzpIDMgmtHttpBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice']/wsdl:service[@name='MzpIDMgmt']/wsdl:port[@name='HTTPEndpoint']    C:\dev\AssociateEntityService\AssociateEntityService\Service References\MzIdManagementServiceReference\Reference.svcmap 1   1   AssociateEntityService

Warning 3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='MzpIDMgmtHttpBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice']/wsdl:service[@name='MzpIDMgmt']/wsdl:port[@name='SecureHTTPEndpoint']  C:\dev\AssociateEntityService\AssociateEntityService\Service References\MzIdManagementServiceReference\Reference.svcmap 1   1   AssociateEntityService
```

I can't post the WSDL as it is sensitive. Also, it only happens for one of the three generated bindings. Is there a way to supprwess generation of a binding? I found a way to suppress here http://wso2.org/library/3821. It's having problems on the Html binding only.

Answer (score 1):

I used teh article cited to disable the generation of the HttpBinding. BTW, the article is wrong and you have to do "disableREST"